# PhoneGap not loading google fonts or jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, google-font-api

PhoneGap won't load the Google font or the jQuery lib. Here is the code

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and here is the HTML

```
<span style="font-size:24px;">Featured Items</span>
```

Comment: wouldnt let me post photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the `font-family` anywhere.

```
<span style="font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif; font-size:24px;">Featured Items</span>
```

Note that inline styles should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Don't forget to set `font-weight:200;` in the inline styles as well.